# True Color (24 bit) in Terminal Emacs

Tags: emacs, terminal, konsole

I am looking for a good way to have 24 bit color in emacs when using a graphical terminal emulator. 
Konsole, for example, does support escape codes for true color, as documented here: https://github.com/robertknight/konsole/blob/master/user-doc/README.moreColors

My problem is that I do not understand how emacs translates face information into escape sequences for the terminal. I also did not manage whether support for 24 bit color is present somewhere, or whether it is at all possible to implement it with emacs lisp. What I am asking for is a pointer to the relevant Emacs documentation or an informed opinion on whether having true color in terminal-emacs is feasible at the moment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use [xterm-frobs.el](http://www.splode.com/~friedman/software/emacs-lisp/src/xterm-frobs.el) to get 256 color term support (in xterm compatible terminals, like konsole).  i use the TERM setting "xterm-256color".  256 color support has generally been more than sufficient for me, as i don't use *that* many colors in my color scheme.  the aforementioned file attempts to interrogate the terminal to find out how many colors it supports.  i don't know if it should (or could be adapted to) be able to do true color support in konsole.

UPDATE:
Note that as of version 26.1, emacs now has support for true color terminals.  Please see the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50577683/552759) for more details.

Answer (score 21):

This was recently included in emacs 26.1 (28 May 2018),

With this file: `terminfo-24bit.src`

```
# Use colon separators.
xterm-24bit|xterm with 24-bit direct color mode,
  use=xterm-256color,
  setb24=\E[48:2:%p1%{65536}%/%d:%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&%d:%p1%{255}%&%dm,
  setf24=\E[38:2:%p1%{65536}%/%d:%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&%d:%p1%{255}%&%dm,
# Use semicolon separators.
xterm-24bits|xterm with 24-bit direct color mode,
  use=xterm-256color,
  setb24=\E[48;2;%p1%{65536}%/%d;%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&%d;%p1%{255}%&%dm,
  setf24=\E[38;2;%p1%{65536}%/%d;%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&%d;%p1%{255}%&%dm,
```

Run:

```
tic -x -o ~/.terminfo terminfo-24bit.src
```

Now you can start emacs with truecolor.

```
TERM=xterm-24bit emacs -nw
```

See the faq: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Colors-on-a-TTY.html

Comment: Emacs reverts to no colors when I use the above approach. This is with emacs 26.1. What could I be doing wrong? I

Comment: It may depend on your terminal, this works for me with gnome-terminal, urxvt & st.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no built-in support for this, as 24bit color space in terminal is quite uncommon(!?). However, given that Emacs is open for you to [add your own terminal support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617458/terminal-emacs-colors-only-work-with-term-xterm-256color), you can try write a package similar to `xterm-frobs.el`.

BTW, if you only need good color theme in terminal, you can try my package https://github.com/tungd/color-theme-approximate that translates GUI color theme to terminal.

Comment: Indeed, as far as I am aware of, only Konsole and (the Konsole-based) Yakuake support 24 bit colors. However this is not a big problem for me, as it is available on most machins on which I work.

Comment: My original problem was that the reduction of the emacs colors to terminal colors (16 or 256 color) makes some faces extremely hard to read. And because I want to use a light and a dark color theme, manually tweaking the offending colors gets tricky. Your package looks promising, I will check it with my setup.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to enable 24-bit color in emacs:
(code is from emacs's `term.c`)

(Note: a simple way to test if colors are working is by checking `M-x list-colors-display`)

<s>**The correct method** is to set `TERM` to a value which supports direct color (via the `RGB` terminfo capability), if one is available for your terminal (or just try xterm-direct).

These are generally named "(terminalName)-direct" (`xterm-direct`, `vte-direct`, etc.)

ex: `TERM=xterm-direct emacs`, or set TERM properly by configuring your terminal.</s>
**Edit:**
There is a flaw in the implementation of xterm-direct (and related). Certain shades of blue are treated as indexed colors (due to it using the same sequences for rgb and indexed color), and won't render correctly. I recommend using the second method.

```
/* Standard support for 24-bit colors.  */
else if (tigetflag ("RGB") > 0)
  {
    /* ...  */
    tty->TN_max_colors = 16777216;
  }
```

Another option is to use a terminfo file with the nonstandard terminfo capabilities `setf24` and `setb24` (see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50577683/6232794). It's possible that this method is supported in older versions of emacs than the other two

```
const char *fg = tigetstr ("setf24");
const char *bg = tigetstr ("setb24");
/* Non-standard support for 24-bit colors. */
if (fg && bg
    && fg != (char *) (intptr_t) -1
    && bg != (char *) (intptr_t) -1)
  {
    tty->TS_set_foreground = fg;
    tty->TS_set_background = bg;
    tty->TN_max_colors = 16777216;
  }
```

As a last resort hack, you can set the environment variable `COLORTERM` to "truecolor", which might work with your terminal.

```
/* Fall back to xterm+direct (semicolon version) if requested
   by the COLORTERM environment variable.  */
else if ((bg = getenv("COLORTERM")) != NULL
         && strcasecmp(bg, "truecolor") == 0)
  {
    tty->TS_set_foreground = "\033[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e38;2;%p1%{65536}%/%d;%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&%d;%p1%{255}%&%d%;m";
    tty->TS_set_background = "\033[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e48;2;%p1%{65536}%/%d;%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&%d;%p1%{255}%&%d%;m";
    tty->TN_max_colors = 16777216;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's feasible, but it can't be done in ELisp alone.

Here's a lovely list of patches to various versions of emacs and tmux to make trucolor life possible:

https://gist.github.com/choppsv1

Comment: Why is tmux required to make this possible in Emacs?